# Маркеры на OSMdroid карте

Tags: java, android

Использую следующий код:

```
MapView map;
LocationManager LM;
StringBuilder sbGPS = new StringBuilder();
private Timer mTimer;
private MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask;
DefaultResourceProxyImpl ResProxy;
ArrayList<OverlayItem> items;
Overlay currentOverlay;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

GPSloc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.GPSloc);
map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
LM = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

mTimer = new Timer();
mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 0, 1000);

    items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    ResProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
    MC = map.getController();

    map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("xUSSR.Roads.Visicom 2.0",null, 14, 19, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {}));
    map.setClickable(true);
    map.setUseDataConnection(false);
    map.setMaxZoomLevel(19);
    map.setMinZoomLevel(14);
    MC.setZoom(16);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(false);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(47.990554, 37.800179);
    MC.setCenter(startPoint);
    MC.animateTo(startPoint);

public LocationListener location = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
        OverlayItem myLocation = new OverlayItem(null, null, point);
        Drawable myMarker = map.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.human);
        myLocation.setMarker(myMarker);
        items.add(0, myLocation);
        }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                checkEnabled();
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                checkEnabled();
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            };

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
            TimeCount = TimeCount +1;
    if (TimeCount == 1 * 60){
        GeoPoint task = new GeoPoint(47.990381, 37.799492);
        OverlayItem TaskItem = new OverlayItem(null, null, task);
        Drawable TaskMarker = map.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.target_monstr);
        TaskItem.setMarker(TaskMarker);
        items.add(1, TaskItem);
    }
    if (TimeCount == 2 * 60){
        GeoPoint human = new GeoPoint(47.987854, 37.798934);
        OverlayItem TaskHumanItem = new OverlayItem(null, null, human);
        Drawable TaskHumanMarker = map.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.target_human);
        TaskHumanItem.setMarker(TaskHumanMarker);
        items.add(2, TaskHumanItem);
    }
    AddMerker();
  });
        }
    }

    public void AddMerker (){
if (!items.isEmpty()){
    currentOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
        new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
            public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) { return true; }
            public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) { return false; }
        }, ResProxy);
        map.getOverlays().add(currentOverlay);
        map.invalidate();
    }
    }
```

Получаю вылет при добавлении любого маркера. В чем беда? Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в списках и замещении элементов.
Для  создания пустого маркера, которым заменяется маркер в ArrayList, в PaintNET был создан  пустой слой (прозрачный) pust. Нулевой маркер выглядит так:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
NullItem = new OverlayItem(null, null, point);
Drawable Marker = map.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pust);
NullItem.setMarker(Marker);
```

Работающий код, позволяющий в любой момент времени добавить и удалить любой маркер, стал выглядеть так:

```
double lat = 0;
double lon = 0;

MapView map;
LocationManager LM;
StringBuilder sbGPS = new StringBuilder();
private Timer mTimer;
private MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask;
DefaultResourceProxyImpl ResProxy;
ArrayList<OverlayItem> items;
ArrayList<OverlayItem> subItems;  // Дополнительный список
Overlay currentOverlay;
OverlayItem NullItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

GPSloc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.GPSloc);
map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
LM = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

mTimer = new Timer();
mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 0, 1000);

items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
subItems = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
// Нулевой маркер
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
NullItem = new OverlayItem(null, null, point);
Drawable Marker = map.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pust);
NullItem.setMarker(Marker);
//
subItems.add(0, NullItem);
ResProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
MC = map.getController();

map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("xUSSR.Roads.Visicom 2.0",null, 14, 19, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {}));
map.setClickable(true);
map.setUseDataConnection(false);
map.setMaxZoomLevel(19);
map.setMinZoomLevel(14);
MC.setZoom(16);
map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
map.setMultiTouchControls(false);
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(47.990554, 37.800179);
MC.setCenter(startPoint);
MC.animateTo(startPoint);

public LocationListener location = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lon = location.getLongitude();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                checkEnabled();     }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                checkEnabled();     }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}  }; 

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
// Здесь может быть прочий код исполняемый при работе таймера

Markers();
});
    }
}

    public void Markers(){
    if (!items.isEmpty()){
        items.clear(); // Очистка списка, у меня только так удаляются все маркеры
    }
    if (lat == 0){   // Если GPS еще не дал координат
        items.add(0, NullItem); // добавится нулевой маркер
    }
    else {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
        OverlayItem myLocation = new OverlayItem(null, null, point);
        Drawable myMarker = map.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.human);
        myLocation.setMarker(myMarker);
        items.add(myLocation);
    }
          // Добавляем все маркеры из дополнительного списка
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()){
        for (int i = 1; i<tasks.size(); i++){ // Начинаем добавлять с 1 т.к. 0 уже занят
            items.add(i, tasks.get(i));
        }
    }
    currentOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
        new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Показывает название маркера если оно задано
                    return true; }
                public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {   return true; }
        }, ResProxy);
        map.getOverlays().clear();   // У меня слой не очищается
        map.getOverlays().add(currentOverlay);
        map.invalidate();

    }
        // Добавлятор маркеров
private void addMarkers (String Txt, double tLat, double tLon){
    GeoPoint mark = new GeoPoint(tLat, tLon);
    OverlayItem SubItem = new OverlayItem(Txt, null, mark);
    Drawable marker = map.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.а);
    SubItem.setMarker(marker);
    subItems.add(SubItem);
}
        // Удалятор маркеров 
 private void removeMarkers (int remIndex){
    subItems.remove(remIndex); //Удаляем маркер
    subItems.add(remIndex, NullItem); //записываем на место удаленного нулевой маркер
}
```

При добавлении каждый новый маркер будет иметь индекс +1 начиная с 0. Ф-ция удаления будет замещать удаляемый маркер пустым, при этом нумерация не изменится.